# AsyncTask and JSOUP playing nicely together

Tags: java, android-asynctask, jsoup

I've been working on a personal bar taplist which parses a webpage using JSOUP for listed beers and, more importantly here, the last change date. The problem here is that when I load the activity, the parsed content does not appear until I manually intervene and hold my finger over a button leading to another activity.
Within my "public class MainScreen..." my relevant code looks like this:

```
 public class MainScreen extends ExpandableListActivity 
implements    OnChildClickListener { 
    ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ListView mListView; ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> ArrayOfBeerNames; 
    ArrayList<Beer> ArrayOfBeers; 
    ExpandableListView expandbleLis;

         @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taplist);
    expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();    

    expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandbleLis.setClickable(true);


    ArrayOfBeerNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayOfBeers = new ArrayList<Beer>();

    new AsyncDerp().execute();

}

private class AsyncDerp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog LoginProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        LoginProgressDialog.setMessage("Fetching the up-to-date list...");
        LoginProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        processUpdate();

        return null;
    }

        private void processUpdate() {
    String URL = "http://www.dogfish.com/restaurant/menus/brews-whats-on-tap.htm";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")
                .get();

        Elements updates = doc.select("p:matches(.+?)+p");            
        for(Element update: updates) {

            String TheUpdateTextWeGot = update.text();

            if((TheUpdateTextWeGot.contains("updated")))
            {
                String updatedate = "Current as of " + TheUpdateTextWeGot.substring(9, 20) + ".";       
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(updatedate);
            }
        }

        if(mData.size() == 0) {
            mData.add("Empty result");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        mData.clear();
        mData.add("Exception: " + ex.toString());
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
{

    LoginProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
    }
}
```

I realize that there are a few things going on here as many SE posts have reminded me. It is using Async to download the page and parse it but the app should be displaying the data automatically too without me having to intervene and force it to do so.

Where am I going wrong here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where is ur mData coming from though? As in where is it defined?

Comment: (Sorry about formatting) Immediately preceding the code above:
`public class MainScreen extends ExpandableListActivity implements OnChildClickListener {
    
 ArrayList<String> mData =  new ArrayList<String>();
 ListView mListView;
 ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
 
 ArrayList<String> ArrayOfBeerNames;
 ArrayList<Beer> ArrayOfBeers;
 
 ExpandableListView expandbleLis;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
public class MainScreen extends ExpandableListActivity 
implements    OnChildClickListener { 
    ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ListView mListView; ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> ArrayOfBeerNames; 
    ArrayList<Beer> ArrayOfBeers; 
    ExpandableListView expandbleList;
    Document doc;
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taplist);
    expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();    

    expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandbleLis.setClickable(true);


    ArrayOfBeerNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayOfBeers = new ArrayList<Beer>();

    new progression().execute();
}


public class progression extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                MainScreen.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setCancelable(true);
            this.dialog
                    .setMessage("Fetching the up-to-date list..., Please Wait.......");
            this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            this.dialog.setProgress(0);
            this.dialog.setMax(1000);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                /*
                 * This is run on a background thread, so we can sleep here or
                 * do whatever we want without blocking UI thread. A more
                 * advanced use would download chunks of fixed size and call
                 * publishProgress();
                 */


   String URL = "http://www.dogfish.com/restaurant/menus/brews-whats-on-tap.htm";
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")
                .get();



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //mData.clear();
        //mData.add("Exception: " + ex.toString());
    }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                /*
                 * The task failed
                 */

            }

            /*
             * The task succeeded
             */
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(params);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            super.onPostExecute(unused);


            Elements updates = doc.select("p:matches(.+?)+p");            
        for(Element update: updates) {

            String TheUpdateTextWeGot = update.text();

            if((TheUpdateTextWeGot.contains("updated")))
            {
                String updatedate = "Current as of " + TheUpdateTextWeGot.substring(9, 20) + ".";       
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(updatedate);
            }
        }

        if(mData.size() == 0) {
            mData.add("Empty result");
        }

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {

                this.dialog.dismiss();

            }
            /*
             * Update here your view objects with content from download. It is
             * save to dismiss dialogs, update views, etc., since we are working
             * on UI thread.
             */

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What do I do with the *DailyWord*.this.getActivity and the *Log*.e("tag",...)? They cannot be resolved, etc..

Comment: Right, silly changes. I should have picked those two up. The second time we refer to "doc" it cannot be resolved to how we defined it up above. What do?

Comment: Here define it where u put the Arraylist MData. i will edit it now check

Comment: BOOM! SUCCESS! Very smooth, too! Thank you.